# JDBC template execute a select query multiple times

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I have a query somewhat like below

```
select STUDENT_REGN from STUDENT where STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType
```

User can give a max 5 different combinations of `student_roll` and `student_roll_type` which is uniquely used to identify a student. I want to execute this query via named parameter jdbc template.

But the problem is that I will have to run this query in a loop 5 times for 5 different user inputs. Is there a way I can fetch records for all 5 combinations in a single database call so as to achieve better performance?

I cannot do a select * and filter out records in my code since the table has huge number of records.
I am also not allowed to build dynamic queries during runtime.

Comment: How do you receive the parameters? 10 separate values? List of objects with 2 fields? Something else?

Comment: It is a rest API and I would receive the params as an array of objects having several other fields along with `student_roll` and `student_roll_type`. This array has a max limit of 5 elements. So the request can be anywhere between 1 - 5 objects.

Answer (score 0):

not easily. you can write a UNION, or, use `IN`, or, use parens and `AND` and `OR`:

```
select STUDENT_REGN from STUDENT where STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll1
  and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType1

UNION

select STUDENT_REGN from STUDENT where STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll2
  and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType2

...
```

works, though you'd have to 'hardcode' the '5 combinations' part, and you'd always have to specify 10 actual values (from `stRoll1` and `rType1` to 5), even if there are fewer than 5. Another alternative is that you write some code to construct this query first.

Similar trickery can be used instead of UNION:

```
select STUDENT_REGN from STUDENT where STUDENT_ROLL IN (:stRoll)
  and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE IN (:rType)
```

But [1] this may not be what you want (any combination of any rType and any stRoll would then match, I think you want all students that match a specific roll/type combo, not 'any student whose roll is any of these and whose type is any of these', and [2] I'm not entirely sure that jdbctemplate is capable of turning a single `?` into multiple `?, ?, ?` scaled to the size of the list input.

Which leaves:

```
select STUDENT_REGN from STUDENT where 
  (STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll1 and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType1) OR
  (STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll2 and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType2) OR
  (STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll3 and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType3) OR
  (STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll4 and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType4) OR
  (STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll5 and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType5);
```

You can construct this one too, somewhat easily (remember, `where false OR ...` works just as well, and a query optimizer is not going to be slowed down by this meaningless `or` - thus giving you an easy simple string that you can repeatedly add (`" OR (STUDENT_ROLL = :stRoll" + idx + " and STUDENT_ROLL_TYPE = :rType" + idx + ")"`).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Unfortunately in my case, I am not allowed to build dynamic query during runtime. Having said that, which one would be the best way (performance wise) to achieve this?

Comment: if you don't have proper indices, they all stink and cause a full table scan; the first one probably 5 full table scans, so probably you want the third one. If you do have proper indices, they're all fast.

Comment: @derek What do you mean "not allowed to build dynamic query"? It is what is needed, really, but since you're limited to max 5 pairs, use the last query shown in answer as a *workaround*. If you have less than 5 pairs, simply repeat the values of the first pair to fill in the missing values. Repeating a pair will not cause duplicate query results.